# Sci-fi book about a boy in space who can use the elements and goes back in time when he dreams

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, magic, space

They're in space in the future, but when he dreams he travels back in time. On the planet, everyone can use the elements, like in *Avatar: The Last Airbender*. Also, there's a magic sword or something.

Comment: Hi. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: A scifi book set in space with elemental magic *and* time-travel sounds like a [hat on a hat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/put_a_hat_on_a_hat#:~:text=Verb,over%20the%20top%20quotations%20%E2%96%BC) *on another hat*.